# TiddlyWiki: Filter table of contents by multiple tags

Tags: tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

I have a tiddlywiki with multiple roleplay game notes in it. Every tiddly is tagged with its respective game name and a category (e.g. "city" or "NPC").

Now I want to create a table of contents that list only, for example, NPCs of one game. And I would like to do it with the `toc`.

My current code is this:

```
<div class="tc-table-of-contents">
<<toc 'NPC'>>
</div>
```

However, this gives me ALL NPCs. How can I add another tag as filter criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably too late to help you out, but for anyone else who happens upon this question, the `sort` parameter of the `toc` macro can include an arbitrary filter step or steps, so you can do:

```html
<div class="tc-table-of-contents">
<<toc 'NPC' sort:"tag[SecondTag]">>
</div>
```

See [Table-of-Contents Macros](https://tiddlywiki.com/#Table-of-Contents%20Macros) for a full description of the options for `toc` and its siblings.

---

If you want the filter to match multiple criteria ANDed together, you can say, e.g., `tag[one]tag[two]`. An OR condition isn't really designed to work here, though, as you need multiple [filter runs](https://tiddlywiki.com/#Filter%20Run) to do an OR condition in a filter, and the `sort` command is expecting only filter steps.

Here's a hack that appears to work for an OR condition as of 5.1.23:

```html
<div class="tc-table-of-contents">
<<toc 'TableOfContents' sort:"tag[one]][all[shadows+tiddlers]tag<__tag__>!has[draft.of]tag[two]">>
</div>
```

However, this is essentially doing an injection attack on the `toc` macro, so I wouldn't trust it to continue working if I were you. If you need something this complicated, you would probably be better rigging something up yourself with a `$list` widget or three than trying to use the `toc` macro.

Comment: Accepted! :D Thank you! Can you also show how to give multiple tags in the sort argument? The documentation does not make this clear (at least what I saw).